# how can I export data to different files by looking one column?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I want to export data by looking 'owner' column.

```
sql:
select * from all_source
where tpe='PROCEDURE'
```

and I want to save file like ;

```
'schema1procs.prc'
'schema2procs.prc'
'schema3procs.prc'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `select` and store the result in text file. Then use this text file to create a loop for export the data:
`select.sql`:

```
set newpage 0; 
set echo off; 
set feedback off; 
set heading off; 
set underline off
select owner,tpe from all_source
where tpe='PROCEDURE'
```

Get schemas:

```
sqlplus user/password @select.sql|awk '{print $1}'>file.txt
```

and do exports

```
for i in `cat file.txt`
do
expdp user/password DUMPFILE=${i}procs.prc SCHEMAS=${i}
done
```

Of course you should tune export by your requirements